# What is the difference between "class C extends A with B" and "class C extends B" when trait B extends trait A

Tags: class, scala, traits

When two traits are defined like this,

```
trait A
trait B extends A
```

what is the difference between these two.

```
class C extends B
class D extends A with B
```

I do not think it is necessary for class C or D to extends trait A since trait B already extends trait A.

Why is this often written "class D extends A with B" ?

Answer (score 6):

It's a pretty good question... I'll **try** to answer with a subjective response.

I guess that extends `A` mixin with `B` is important when the hierarchy will be linearized, in this particular case there is no differences but what if you mixin `D` with another trait `E` that reimplements some (but not all) functions from A which aren't well advised in `B` for your needs in `D`. So you'd have

```
class D extends A with E with B
```

Moreover in that case, we keep the meaning that `D` **is** a `A`

Comment: `D` is an `A` in both cases, because `B` is an `A`, no?

Comment: Sure it is, but I'm talking about the sense of **extends** (semantic). Extension is much closer to **is** than mixin, would could be said **like**. Think about how are dealt the Collections post 2.8, where new Traits have been created to contain implementation of Collection function like (foreach). Which are name SeqLike, TraversableLike an so on

Comment: We can endlessly debate various degrees of "being". From the point of view of the type system, "is a" means subtyping and there is no distinction between extending or mixing in.